# How to blur a Raster in Paper.js

Tags: canvas, paperjs

It seems there is no filters and no way to approch canvas context in paperjs.

So what's the best pratice to make Item blur in paperjs?

Answer (score 5):

You can access a `Raster`'s `<canvas>` element via `Raster.canvas`, then blur that canvas and use the blurred canvas to redraw it.

Here's an example:

```
var raster = new Raster({
    source: 'http://assets.paperjs.org/images/marilyn.jpg',
    crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
    position: view.center,
    visible: false
})

raster.onLoad = function() {
    this.canvas.getContext('2d').filter = 'blur(10px)'
    this.drawImage(this.canvas, 0, 0) 
    this.visible = true
}
```

and here's a [POC Paper.js Sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/TZDBasMwDIZfxeTiBIrT7RjYaafBYLAdlx0UR03dJrKRnKSl9N3nrBnE+CJ+69Mn3zKCAbMq+zpjtMdsl1nfLvUErBgkIqsXRTirz78iv9Wk0hE/ssVK6WOMoSpLEMEoJkBAPonx3JVugA6lHIBdfyVzCp3ePZote5EPdp2jRADydB38KP9x8OKi8ymbHM7GIqXBazY5cU2fBh+gF6zpXtRU00PUeHr30Cbfw0h2IeSFWn3j0YmxQBOI6TC++sS8xFw/t7owB9c/9tRNP3L+tA+XQm/6Wob5bdkm32B2ap9uoTbvVrkEijwucuk7G0Y4B+8oSlZ9/9x/AQ==).

For other `Item`s other than `Raster`, you are going to have to use `item.rasterize()` to turn it into a `Raster` and then use the method illustrated above. You are going to also need to scale the image bounds appropriately to accommodate the blur.

Comment: can i use canvas filter to make the image edge to be feather?

Comment: Not sure but check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19038440/canvas-clipping-with-feather-edges-effect. Perhaps you can use this technique on `Raster.canvas`.